# junit http get request compare with csv list

Tags: spring-boot, junit, java-8, stream

the purpose of this request - to get at least some hint/idea of how to do it -
new to java - so does the novice question -

I want to match my csv columns with output of get request
and tell me - matches all of it or no of columns --

```
@RunWith(SpringRunner.class)
@SpringBootTest(classes = TestApplication.class)
//@WebMvcTest(value = SwProductController.class)
@ActiveProfiles("dev") // In case you want to test a particular profile
@AutoConfigureMockMvc
public class SwProductImplTest
{

        @Autowired
        private MockMvc mockMvc;


        @Test
        public void testRetrieveDetails() throws Exception {

                String filesss = "csv--file--path";
                JSONArray expected = new JSONArray(Files.readAllLines(Paths.get(filesss))
                        .stream()
                        .map(s -> new yourJson(s.split(",")[0], s.split(",")[1]))
                        .collect(toList()));

                RequestBuilder requestBuilder = MockMvcRequestBuilders
                        .get("/swproduct/list")
                        .accept(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON);

                MvcResult result = mockMvc.perform(requestBuilder).andReturn();
                //System.out.println(result.getResponse());

                JSONAssert.assertEquals(result.getResponse().getContentAsString(), expected, false);


        }

        private class yourJson {
                String s;
                String s1;


                public yourJson(String s, String s1) {
                        this.s = s;
                        this.s1 = s1;

                }
        }
}
```

Output of get request looks like this -
[get-request](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GEnCn.png)

csv file -

```
sw product,sw product module,technology
Product 1,Module 1,REGULAR
Product 1,Module 2,SPRING CLOUD
Product 2,Module 1,REGULAR
Product 2,Module 3,REGULAR
```

Comment: JSONArray expected = new JSONArray(Files.readAllLines(Paths.get(filesss)) -- outcome null -- [null,null,null,null,null,null,null,null]

Answer (score 0):

Both the data are the same but the only difference is that your output is in JSON format while the example you post is in tabular form. Both will work fine